# Authentication on CRM 2013 with NLB

Tags: authentication, dynamics-crm-2013, nlb

I have a problem of authentication on a vanilla CRM2013 installed on a NLB. The crm 2013 is working correctly if i use the ip address of the NLB, but if i try to access the NLB using is unique name, it's prompting for credentials and is not authenticating the user (the user is the one that i used for the setup process). Anyone has ever seen something like this? I try to fiddler the request and beside a small difference in a cookie request in the header to me they look the same. Also if i ping the unique name of the NLB it responds with the correct ip address.
The last test that i did was add the name in the host file, and i had the same problem (no authentication), looks like is managing to get to the server but it fails to authenticate. I tried to use localhost address and it worked (on both the single servers), and it worked with the name of the 2 servers that are part of my cluster, it worked with the ip of those servers too. Anyone has any idea why with the ip address of the NLB everything is working as i expect and as soon as I use the name is not working?

Recap:

```
Address         |Status
-------------------------
CRM1.com        |working
192.168.1.CRM1  |working
CRM2.com        |working
192.168.1.CRM2  |working
192.168.1.NLB   |working
NLB.com         |not working
```

Obviously this is sample data, and I know that with the single server i will not use the NLB, I was expecting to have issues with both the Ip and the servername, not with just one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the reason is not working. When you install behind a NLB you need to change some parameters in iss. Since I'm not very good at managing it in the config editor you need to change the section, and update 2 keyvalues from false to true. Step 2-10 of this guide http://blogs.msdn.com/b/niran_belliappa/archive/2014/02/17/network-load-balancing-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013.aspx